# C++ access violation when calling instance method

Tags: c++, function, methods, directx, access-violation

I'm creating a DirectX 11 helper class that looks kind of like this:

```
#import "DXClass.h" // I have declared the constructor and the other methods here
// All of the DirectX libraries are imported in the header as well 

DXClass::DXClass()
{

    // Pointers created, etc.
}

DXClass:~DXClass()
{
    // Other DirectX objects released   

    // With an if (bbSRView) {}, the exception still occurs, so bbSRView is not NULL
    // bbSRView is a ID3D11ShaderResourceView*
    // When the other violation does not occur, one does here:
    bbSRView->Release();
    bbSRView = NULL;

    // More releases

void DXClass::Initialize()
{
    SetupDisplay();

    // Other initialization that works fine
}

void DXClass::SetupDisplay()
{
    // This is where the debugger shows the access violation.
    // factory is declared as DXGIFactory*
    HRESULT hr = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void **)&factory);

    // Loop through adapters and outputs, etc.
}
```

This class is initialized like this: `dxClass = new DXClass();`
The `Initialize()` function is called in another method of the class that created `dxClass`.

When the application is run, I get an access violation at the beginning of the `setupDisplay()` function. However, if I take the code in `setupDisplay()` and put it in `Initialize()`, removing the call to `setupDisplay()`, no access violation occurs. Also, if I remove the code from `setupDisplay()` so that it is an empty function, and then call it in `Initialize()`, no access violation occurs.

It appears that no pointers are NULL, and the application will start fine if it is changed as described above. However, on another note, the application receives another access violation when quitting. The debugger points to a `Release()` call on an `ID3D11ShaderResourceView*`, which I have pointed out in my code snippet. This pointer also appears to be valid.

I have also checked the similar questions, but the `this` pointer of the class appears to be valid, and I am not creating any buffers that could be overflowing. There also isn't anything that could be deleting/freeing the object early.

I have no idea what could be causing the errors. :/

Thanks :D

EDIT:
Here's an isolated test, with the same errors:
I have in my main function:

```
INT APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, INT)
{
    App *app = new App();
    app->Run();
    app->Release();
 }
```

In my `App` class, I have removed all window functionality and any other variables so that it looks like this:

```
App::App()
{
    dxClass = new DXClass();
}

App::~App()
{
    delete dxClass;
}

void App::Run()
{
    dxClass->Initialize();

    while (true) {} // Never reaches here
}
```

The access violation still occurs at the same place. Also, same results if I replace the factory instance variable with:

```
IDXGIFactory *f;
HRESULT hr = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void **)&f);
```

Which has worked for me in other applications.

Comment: I doubt that the error is in the code you show, but rather it is somewhere else where you *use* the code. Make a minimal, self-contained test case and post *that* rather than fragments.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to say what is going on. By the way, you should use CComPtr, it will make your life a lot easier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The variable most likely to be causing the problem, `factory`, comes out of nowhere. No code shows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An access violation when calling Release() usually means the object has already received it's final Release() from somewhere else (and it has destroyed itself). One possible solution would be to AddRef() when passing the pointer into your DXClass

Comment: I agree that this sounds like a classic use-after-free scenario.

Comment: Thanks - I figured it out. I few lines below `CreateDXGIFactory()` I was performing I logical NOT (`!adapter`) when adapter was never initialized or set to NULL. :S I think that error was also somehow causing the `Release()` error indirectly, since now everything works.